# Turn SQL rows into columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

i have imported lots of building-data from another system into MS SQL 2017 but facing a problem turning rows into columns. Most fields are var-chars in the system imported from and a field can have leading/trailing spaces. Believe me when i say, i have searched many places/pages for an answer.

```
data:
key1   Unit       Measurement 
04A    Unit 1     156,8000
04A    Unit 2     5.845,3000
678R   Unit 1     8,6000
678R   Unit 2     409,6000
678R   Unit 3     17

how can data be turned into:
key1   Unit 1     Unit 2       Unit 3
04A    156,8000   5.845,3000   NULL
678R   8,6000     409,6000     17
```

measurement column - should this be float or decimal - we are scandinavians here :-) ?

i have tried pivot with max as aggregate function but too many rows appear with nulls in Unit 1 , 2 , 3 - it even rejects rows having value

Comment: "too many rows appear with nulls in Unit" my guess is that you are pivoting on a set of columns that are more than these 3. The pivot operation does an implicit group by by all the columns from the set you are pivoting. Make sure to only pre-select these 3 columns before applying the pivot operator. Please add DML + DDL so it's easier to build an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to limit the pivot's column set before actually applying it:

```
;WITH PrePivot AS -- Limit the columns for the PIVOT's GROUP BY
(
    SELECT
        Key1,
        Unit,
        Measurement
    FROM
        YourTable
)
SELECT
    P.Key1,
    P.[Unit 1],
    P.[Unit 2],
    P.[Unit 3]
FROM
    PrePivot AS T
    PIVOT (
        MAX(T.Measurement) FOR T.Unit IN ([Unit 1], [Unit 2], [Unit 3])
    ) AS P
```

Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53881131/4608204) to see how `PIVOT` actually does an implicit `GROUP BY` with all non-pivoting columns.

Comment: @tvviewer Then this "-" value are actually 3 different values probably with unseen characters. I can't fix what I can't reproduce, please try adding some sample data on the question. Try using LEN(P.Key1) to see character length.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this example on my real data which is a little different from example. It does return rows but it does not return one row per building. I get 3 rows for 678R: 1: with Unit 1: 8,6000 Unit 2: NULL Unit 3: NULL        2: Unit 1: NULL, Unit 2: 409,6  Unit 3 NULL     3: Unit 1: NULL, Unit 2: NULL , Unit 3: 17

Comment: @tvviewer I can't reproduce what you say, I get 1 row per Key1. Please modify your question with the real data.

Comment: Should all varchar fields be trim() so that they can be compared properly in the pivot view?

Comment: SQL Server does string comparisons with trimmed values by default. Try doing a `SELECT DISTINCT Key1 FROM ...` and see if even then you get 3 different values. If so then you need to update them accordingly so they match (you can do this on the subquery).

Comment: It seems i got it working better so far with all suggestings in the thread. I had included a few columns that did not belong in the pivot view. I have to be very careful and keep an eye on what information is updated at different times by different persons. This info should probably be excluded in pivot view because it can cause difficulties when comparing info. Thanks for help. To EzLo - the data is confidential and cannot be pasted in.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM YourTable
)AS FooData
PIVOT(
    AVG(FooData.Measurement)
    FOR Unit IN ([Unit 1], [Unit 2], [Unit 3])
) AS FooPivot
```

An example:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
   key1   varchar(50),
   Unit   VARCHAR(50),
   Measurement DECIMAL(18,8)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    key1,
    Unit,
    Measurement
)
VALUES
  ('04A', 'Unit 1',     156.8000)
, ('04A', 'Unit 2',     5.8453000)
, ('678R', 'Unit 1',     8.6000)
, ('678R', 'Unit 2',     409.6000)
, ('678R', 'Unit 3',     17)
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
)AS FooData
PIVOT(
    AVG(FooData.Measurement)
    FOR Unit IN ([Unit 1], [Unit 2], [Unit 3])
) AS FooPivot
```

OUTPUT:

```
key1    Unit 1            Unit 2        Unit 3
04A     156.80000000    5.84530000      NULL
678R    8.60000000      409.60000000    17.00000000
```

**UPDATE:**

I don't know what actual data type of `Measurement` field which has value `5.845,3000`, however I strongly believe that this data is type of `numeric`. If yes, then it is better to store numerical data as a numerical type as it is responsibility of the presentation layer cause there are different requirements to show numbers in various countries.  To add commas you can use pipes at the client side.

In addition, if `Measurement` is type of number and you store it as `varchar(50)`, then you would get problems while ordering. So it is better to store as `numeric`.

Otherwise, you can use datatype `varchar(255)`:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
   key1   varchar(50),
   Unit   VARCHAR(50),
   Measurement VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    key1,
    Unit,
    Measurement
)
VALUES
  ('04A', 'Unit 1',     '156.8000')
, ('04A', 'Unit 2',     '5,845.3000')
, ('678R', 'Unit 1',     '8.6000')
, ('678R', 'Unit 2',     '409.6000')
, ('678R', 'Unit 3',     '17')
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
)AS FooData
PIVOT(
    MAX(FooData.Measurement)
    FOR Unit IN ([Unit 1], [Unit 2], [Unit 3])
) AS FooPivot
```

Comment: @SurajKumar It is better to store numerical data as a numerical type(assuming that in question, 5.845,3000 is a single number) and for displaying it to user, you can use  pipes at the client side.

Comment: @SurajKumar I've edited my answer. Thanks for comment. I strongly believe it is enough to get back a downvote.

Comment: Measurement has datatype varchar (50). This is probably not the best

Comment: @tvviewer if is is number, there is a chance to get problems while ordering. So it is better to store as numeric.

Comment: Your original assumption was correct, 5.845,3000 = 5,845.3000, is float or decimal, is just formatting, the OP mentioned that are Scandinavian

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using `PIVOT`. Here you need to use `MAX()` function rather than `AVG()` or `SUM()` as data saved is in `varchar`.

```
create table #temp(key1 varchar(10), Unit Varchar(20), Measurement varchar(20))
insert into #temp values
('04A', 'Unit 1', '156,8000'),
('04A', 'Unit 2', '5.845,3000'),
('678R', 'Unit 1', '8,6000'),
('678R', 'Unit 2', '409,6000'),
('678R', 'Unit 3', '17')

SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM #temp
)AS FooData
PIVOT(
    MAX(FooData.Measurement)
    FOR Unit IN ([Unit 1], [Unit 2], [Unit 3])
) AS FooPivot
```

The output is as shown below:

```
key1    Unit 1      Unit 2      Unit 3
04A     156,8000    5.845,3000  NULL
678R    8,6000      409,6000    17
```