# Why I get 4 rows in Pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

**Pivoting Data**

Pivoting is a technique that groups and aggregates data, transitioning it from a state of rows to a state of columns. In all pivot queries, you need to identify three elements:

- What do you want to see on rows? This element is known as the on rows, or *grouping element*
- What do you want to see on columns? This element is known as the on cols, or *spreading element*.
- What do you want to see in the intersection of each distinct row and column value? This element is known as the data, or *aggregation element*.

pattern:

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
  SELECT
    < grouping column >,
    < spreading column >,
    < aggregation column >
  FROM < source table >
)
SELECT < select list >
FROM PivotData
  PIVOT( < aggregate function >(< aggregation column >)
    FOR < spreading column > IN (< distinct spreading values >) ) AS P;
```

I have this table created in SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NameValueData](
    [Name] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [INT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and It has values

```
INSERT INTO NameValueData
VALUES
( 'N1', 1 ), 
( 'N2', 2 ), 
( 'N3', 3 ), 
( 'N4', 4 ),
--NOT FIXED Number of ROWS
```

And data is:

```
Name    Value
N1  1
N2  2
N3  3
N4  4
... ...
```

Now I need to **rotate** this Data and get results where columns names created based on row values from Column Name

```
N1  N2  N3  N4  ...
1   2   3   4   --Can be more
```

I tried to write my own Pivot SQL

```
WITH PivotData
AS (SELECT Value AS GroupingColumn,
           Name AS SpreadingColumn,
           Value AS AggregationColumn
    FROM dbo.NameValueData)
SELECT 1 AS Ignore,
       [N1],
       [N2],
       [N3],
       [N4]
FROM PivotData
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(AggregationColumn)
        FOR SpreadingColumn IN ([N1], [N2], [N3], [N4])
    ) AS P;
```

Result is:

```
Ignore  N1  N2  N3  N4
1   1   NULL    NULL    NULL
1   NULL    2   NULL    NULL
1   NULL    NULL    3   NULL
1   NULL    NULL    NULL    4
```

Why I get 4 rows here?

Comment: Remove the groupingcolumn in the first select and you will see the result you want. The pivot opreator does an implicit `GROUP BY` for all non-referenced columns https://stackoverflow.com/a/53881131/4608204

Comment: Seems SELECT 0 AS GroupingColumn gave me correct result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace `1 AS Ignore` in your select list with `GroupingColumn` you'll see why you are getting 4 records instead of one.

The `PIVOT` operation uses all of the grouping columns whether included in the final projection or not in an implied `group by` clause when performing the aggregation.

Removing `GroupingColumn` from the `PivotData` CTE and from the final projection will resolve your issue.

In fact due to the nature of your data you can completely get rid of the CTE and just use this query:

```
select * 
  from namevaluedata
 pivot (max(value)
        for name in ([N1], [N2], [N3], [N4])
       ) p;
```

Comment: It works, even I still don't  get it  how it works exactly

Comment: It works because the `PIVOT` operator is a convenient shorthand for writing `select max(case name when 'N1' then value end) N1, max(case name when 'N2' then value end) N2, ... from namevaluedata group by ...` in your case you wanted a single group, so you can completely get rid of the grouping columns or ensure they have a static value, and then the `group by` can go away.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH PivotData
AS (SELECT Name AS SpreadingColumn,
           Value AS AggregationColumn
    FROM dbo.NameValueData)
SELECT 1 AS Ignore,
       [N1],
       [N2],
       [N3],
       [N4]
FROM PivotData
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(AggregationColumn)
        FOR SpreadingColumn IN ([N1], [N2], [N3], [N4])
    ) AS P;
```

Comment: SQL works It works, but SQL from Sentinel more compact

Answer (score 0):

I just don't like `pivot` and much prefer conditional aggregation.  And this is one of the reasons.

The rows being generated are determined by all the values in the source data that are *not* in the `PIVOT` clause.  Because you have a third column (`GroupingColumn`) it is used to define the rows.

Comment: yes, THEN WHEN looks much more self explanatory, but I don't know how to make it for my task.